# Buck converter burn MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, buck, mosfet-driver, h-bridge

[image: schematic]

H-bridge buck converter, input is square signal 10 V and Q3 make signal for LI and HI.
VCC is 12 V. Q4 connected to separated 12 V.
Instead of R20 - there will be induction, but so far I put resistor.

[image: PCB]
[image: PCB]

The problem is, that changing input frequency, let's say from 10 to 50 kHz, or duty cycle from 20% to 80%, at some point, transistor (90% of time it's Q4) - burns out (prior was a case when driver burned as well).
It difficult to say why and when it happened, I might change frequency on my functional generator and at some point - transistor burns out. Or I might start changing duty cycle - here - there - and it just burn out.

I don't understand why it happened, since voltage is very low, frequency usually about 10 kHz. There's even no induction yet... This kind of transistor should handle about 80 A.

I burned about 7 transistor and 5 drivers so far.

I have few suspicion why it might happened:

1. Transistors I bought from aliexpress
2. IR2113 - also from aliexpress
3. PCB layout has lots of issues and it might damage somehow transistor

If PCB is bad, can you suggest then how you'd do experiments without doing production PCB, for experimental purposes for particular schematic.

Any other ideas and suggestions are welcome.

**UPDATE Mar, 13**

Changed driver IR2113 to IR2104, which can be controlled by 1 input signal and has inner dead time.

[image]

Made it all on PCB as I was told (PCB tracks were pretty bad, so had to cover them with solder pretty intense, to cover crops, dots, etc)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now oscillograms (related to GND):
Blue - input, Violet - output from driver (LO, HO)

[image: Low side]

[image: High side]

So far, everything works fine, changing frequency or duty cycle - doesn't burn out anything. Tried frequency even 100KHz, works fine.

Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: It is very likely a shoot through issue which means both MOSFETs are turned on at the same time. AC coupling the logic input signals of the driver seems weird and might be part of your problem. Why so you do that?

Comment: Welcome! That isn’t an H-bridge but a synchronous buck without output inductor.

Comment: 10 kHz switcher on a perfboard with no ground plane isn’t happening. Four layer PCBs are 5 USD these days. I’ve burned though tubes of IR2113 and MOSFETs learning this the hard way.

Comment: A carefully constructed perfboard prototype at 10 kHz is certainly possible for proof of concept, but it won't fix the major design errors of the OP's circuit. And scope traces will be necessary for any meaningful analysis and troubleshooting.

Comment: It is very likely a shoot through issue which means both MOSFETs are turned on at the same time - I also thought about it, but since transistors should be able to handle 80 A, they first should start heating. But burning becomes immediate at some point, and they are barely warn @LarsHankeln

Comment: AC coupling the logic input signals of the driver seems weird and might be part of your problem - will try to remove them. Since it's AC signal, should be fine I think. @LarsHankeln

Comment: That isn’t an H-bridge but a synchronous buck without output inductor -- yeah, you're right! @winny

Comment: Four layer PCBs are 5 USD these days -- agree, it's a matter of time to get it delivered. Here is will take 1-2 month to get it from China. So you suggest anyway, even if I'm playing around with such kind of schematic - better to do PCB anyway, rather then perfboard prototype? @winny

Comment: 10 kHz switcher on a perfboard with no ground plane isn’t happening -- at the bottom it's ground thick cooper wire. It is not sufficient? How it should be then? @winny

Comment: _”at the bottom it's ground thick cooper wire”_ Is that wire a flat plane? Do you have any domestic PCB factories if imports are a problem? Or etch it yourself?

Comment: sorry for long delay. Making PCB. Will be back soon

Comment: update is added into main question

Comment: ”at the bottom it's ground thick cooper wire” Is that wire a flat plane? -- it was copper wire, not flat one

Comment: Good to hear that the problem has been resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can show scope traces of the input and output PWM signals I think you will see what is wrong. Poor quality from AliExpress is certainly possible, but more likely poor breadboard layout, lack of low impedance bypass capacitor on U22, insufficient gate voltage on MOSFETs, input voltage spikes (12V) higher than Vdd (5V), and lack of dead time for high/low drive signals.

Please always provide links to datasheets:

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2110-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e

(edit) Also, 50 kHz is much too high for a roughly constructed circuit like this. Make changes to correct the issues pointed out already, and get it working at 10 kHz. If you need a higher frequency, you will need a much neater prototype, or get a PC board made with proper layout and ground plane. Small boards can be obtained for only a few dollars. But get a prototype working properly first, and show your scope waveforms.

Comment: lack of low impedance bypass capacitor on U22 - you mean C5? it's polymer capacitor, that has ESR about 0.05Ohm AFAIR. It's 10x better then low ESR capacitors I have.

Comment: insufficient gate voltage on MOSFETs -- when I measured it - there was neat square 10 V.

Comment: input voltage spikes (12V) higher than Vdd (5V) - that possible might be an issue, but I feed it from functional generator Rigol DG4062, it's quite stable. 10V square in that case it's 5V positive and 5V negative

Comment: and lack of dead time for high/low drive signals -- that's possible might be an issue, since that what I don't have for sure, since I get LI and HI from the same signal and no dead time. But as I said, if transistor can capable to handle 80A, they should start heating, and then burn. And here, no current draw, everything works fine, but at some time - they just burn barely be warm..

Comment: You still need to fix the circuit's deficiencies. Don't use AC coupling. C5 needs low ISR at 10 kHz. So probably use a ceramic 470 nF or so in parallel close to the driver. Use a driver with cross-conduction protection, like IR2304 or IRS2308 (which can be driven with a single signal). And please show images of your scope traces.

Comment: thanks, will do and provide with updates

Comment: Thanks @PStechPaul! Fixed as per your comments, but used IR2104

Answer (score 0):

The input inverter introduces a delay.
From high input to low, *LIN* will be *off* before *HIN* gets to be *on*: fine.
From low to high, *LIN* will be *on* before *HIN* gets to be *off*…
Search for *dead-time* (control/generator) and how to purposefully time these signals or, directly, gate voltages - D5&D6 is a start.